# How to use grep with files in arbitrary encoding, without locale installed and without sudo?

Tags: grep, sudo, locale, character-encoding

I have utf-8 locale on my computer, and i want to search in KOI8-R encoded files. But i don't have KOI8-R locale installed. And i don't have sudo rights to install this locale.

Is it possible to search with grep in this conditions? Can i do a workaround? Convert those encoded files to UTF-8 on the fly, somehow?

PS: I already read this question:
[How to use grep/ack with files in arbitrary encoding?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33574/how-to-use-grep-ack-with-files-in-arbitrary-encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're looking for specific characters (i.e. not using character sets or case-insensitive search), you can make grep look for bytes: convert any non-ASCII character in the regexp to the byte value that represents it in KOI8-R, and invoke grep in the C locale (`LC_ALL=C grep …`, or just `LC_CTYPE=C LC_COLLATE=C grep …`) so that it searches for bytes.

You can use `iconv -f utf-8 -t koi8-r` to convert a string that you type in UTF-8 to KOI8-R even if the KOI8-R locales aren't listed in `locale -a`.

The [`fuseflt` method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33574/how-to-use-grep-ack-with-files-in-arbitrary-encoding/33580#33580) also relies on iconv and doesn't need the locale to be built.