# Search text in files with accent characters

Tags: command-line, search

I would like to search for text with accents in files. I know that I can use grep for searching regular text:

```
grep -rnw './' -e 'KORONA'
```

...but it doesn't work for words with accent characters, like `KORONAVÍRUS`, `obmedzená`.

Any recommendation?

Comment: for *specific* accented letters you could try [equivalence classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#coll) ex. `KORONAV[[=I=]]RUS`

Comment: @steeldriver No it doesn't work for files with mixed encoding. The equivalence class will be created with the encoding applied when executing the command, but a file could have a different encoding. Even a `.` will fail, as the "any character" has to be a character valid in the encoding being used to run the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the encoding of all the files is the same, you just need to write the searched sentence in that encoding. That brings up two possible conditions:

- The encoding on the command line (or where the command is executed) (probably set by one of the `locale` variables `LC_*`) is the same as the encoding of all the files, then, just grep as usual:

  ```
  grep -rn 'KORONAVÍRUS, obmedzená.'
  ```

Use the `-w` option only if you want to match the whole line.

- If the encoding of all files is different, change the search string to that encoding.

  ```
  $ echo 'KORONAVÍRUS, obmedzená.' >orig
  $ grep -ran "$(cat orig | iconv -t CP1252)"
  ```

  Here, the `-a` option allows grep to search inside files with diferent encodings that may be detected as `binary`.

If the files could contain different encodings then there is no solution possible. There is no way to auto-detect a file encoding.

It is **not** possible to search inside a list of files if the files doesn't have an uniform encoding.

Related:
[How to use grep/ack with files in arbitrary encoding?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33574/how-to-use-grep-ack-with-files-in-arbitrary-encoding)

Comment: Nice one! No need to use an intermediate file though: `grep -a "$(echo 'KORONAVÍRUS, obmedzená.' | iconv -t CP1252)"` also works :)